# Tagging and Categorizing text automatically using NLP and Ontology respectively

Tags: nlp, ontology, owl, dotnetrdf

I am working on a project in which user adds some text into Database, and while saving also adds tags to his/her entry, so that others can search using those tags.

EXAMPLE:

TEXT: "Next Formula 1 race is in Spain"

TAGS: "Formula 1", "race", Spain"

if any user will search for these tags will get this entry in the results.

But i want users who search for "Sports" or "Motor Sport" or "Europe" should also get this entry, although these tags were not explicitly tagged into the entry, but are related because "Formula 1" is type of "Motor Sport" which is a type of "Sport" and  "Spain" is in "Europe".

At the moment on my submission form, users write their text in one text box, and then write their tags into the second text box below, and submit.

these tags are later then categorized manually by the admin. So in the above case the admin will manually put "Spain" as the child element of "Europe". (MS SQL Server Hierarchy Column)

I think this can be achieved using some Ontologies software. dotNetRdf, OWL ... but am not sure. I just go to know about this side of the world few days back, and I am not sure how these can help me. Is this the solution, or am I looking into completely wrong thing? Any suggestions to achieve the above?

Also, before doing the categorization, I would want to automatically pick tags from the text and fill in to the lower text box as Tags.

For this I guess I'll have to use some NLP service? Any ideas which one to use, or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Ontologies might be helpful if the relationships you are looking for are general enough (i.e. countries and continents). For the semantic relatedness "race" vs "sport". I would recommend some kind of semantic similarity between words (or tags) that you can exploit.

Basically, if you generate a MxM matrix modelling the dependency/similarity between different tags you can then use those weights to get similar concepts. For instance "race" and "sport" will be much more related than "race" and "spain" for instance.

How to compute the weights? This can be address by several techniques such as [Explicit Semantic Analysis] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_semantic_analysis) or [Distributional Semantics] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributional_semantics) techniques. One of the simplest metrics would be using some coocurrence metric (i.e. % of documents "race" and "sport" appear together).

In addition, you can also use more NLP techniques such as synonyms.

You can also combine these weights with ontological relationships. If you know Spain is part of Europe you can boost their weight in the general matrix.

For the extraction of tags, you should look into Entity Extraction, [nltk](http://nltk.org/) could be a good tool to start with.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are using (MS SQL Server Hierarchy Column) could be complemented in this case by an OWL ontology (which are be a hierarchy/taxonomy). I give you an example of how it would look like in your case and what you can get out of it.

The ontology related to sports would look like:

```
Class: Sport

Class: Formula_1
  SubClassOf: Motor_Sport

Class: Motor_Sport
  SubClassOf: Sport
```

Then with the help of a program called a *reasoner* you can ask queries such as: *What are the things that are more specific than* `Sport`? (subclasses of `Sport`)

The list of results contains `Motor_Sport` and `Formula_1`. You can then use these classes to annotate your data for instance.

A good way to get started is to look at the [Protégé OWL Tutorial](http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/tutorials/protegeowltutorial/).

Comment: thanks for that @loopasam. Am a beginner into this world of Ontologies/Taxonomy/NLP. Your tutorial site will definitely help. I'll go through it in detail. But I think i am confused a little here ... for example like you mentioned above that Motor_Sport will become a subclass of Formula_1. Who will categorize Motor_Sports under Formula_1 at the first place. Does this happen automatically? Or some will have to do it manually?

Comment: The assertion `Motor_Sport` as being a super class of `Formula_1` is done manually. That's the only way to do it, this is how you specify your domain knowledge. Then once the ontology is built you can query it as indicated in my answer. The advantage here is that you have to curate the information only once, and then you exploit it for the rest of the time. Some ontologies already exist out there, so I suggest that you start googling for the domain you are looking for before building your own. If you find one that suits you, you can then use it for your problem.